# Open app of Android located inside a project folder with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

We have project called: "MYAwsomeProject". In this folder we have some config files, .github folder..etc.. But, we have a folder called `code`. Here, inside `code`. We have the android project.

With Android Studio I open the folder "code" to load de Android project. But the question is..

Is possible to open project "root" folder (MYAwsomeProject), and tell AS, that the folder "code" is a Android project?

The goal to open in that way, is because we have some other folders in root project, that contain some scripts, etc.. And instead of open 2 IDEs, work only with one

Structure similar to this:

[image]